# Get 10-day forecast script

Tags: python, beginner

I coded a script to print a 10-day forecast for any location to my terminal.

As I am just learning Python (coming from the PHP world - yes, I know...) and have no buddies coding in Python, I would really appreciate it if anyone could review my code and provide comments and suggestions for improving it.

For starters, I know I am missing docstrings but I left that part for later as I am still reading about it.

Not sure if I need to mention it, but lookup_by_location() and _call() are overriding methods from Weather ancestor class.

Code is also available in [a git repo](https://github.com/armin-meth/tdwreport).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import requests
from weather import Weather
from weather import models

class WeatherReport(Weather):
    def __init__(self, location):
        Weather.__init__(self)
        self.get_report(location)   

    def get_report(self, location): 
        self.show_location(location)
        [self.show_weather(day) for day in self.get_days(self.lookup_by_location(location))]

    def lookup_by_location(self, location):
        url = "%s?q=select* from weather.forecast " \
              "where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='%s') and u='c' &format=json" % (self.URL, location)
        results = self._call(url)
        return results

    def get_days(self, place):
        days = []
        [self.get_day(days, item['date'], item['low'], item['high'], item['text']) for item in place.forecast()]
        return days

    def get_day(self, days, date, low, high, text):
        days.append([date, int(low), int(high), text])

    def show_weather(self, day):
        from_to = "%d-%d" % (day[1], day[2])
        print " "*2 + "%s:" % (day[0]), from_to.rjust(5) + u'\u00b0' + "C -", "%s" % (day[3])

    def show_location(self, location):
        print "-" * 50
        feedback = "10-day forecast for " + location.capitalize()
        print feedback.center(50)
        print "-" * 50

    def _call(self, url):
        results = requests.get(url).json()
        if int(results['query']['count']) > 0:
            wo = models.weather_obj.WeatherObject(results['query']['results']['channel'])
            return wo
        else:
            print 'No results found.'
            quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('tdwreport')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', default="sarajevo", help='get forecast for this location')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 0.2')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    report = WeatherReport(args.location)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tip: Instead of *gluing* constant and variable parts into string with `+` as e. g. in your statement

```
print " "*2 + "%s:" % (day[0]), from_to.rjust(5) + u'\u00b0' + "C -", "%s" % (day[3])
```

use the `format()` method with placeholders `{}` in formatted string:

```
print "  {} {:>5}{}C - {}"     .format(day[0], from_to, u'\u00b0', day[3])
```

(I visually separated the resulting string with placeholders from the format() method),
or - more descriptively - use *names* in `{}` placeholders

```
print "  {day0} {from_to:>5}{degree_sign}C - {day3}" \
    .format(day0=day[0], from_to=from_to, degree_sign=u'\u00b0', day3=day[3])
```

*Format specifier* `>5` after `:` does the same thing as `.rjust(5)` in your code.

---

**Edit:**

For Unicode symbols (as `u'\u00b0'` in your code) use their hexadecimal value (`0x00b0`) and type `c` in the placeholder:

```
print "  {} {:>5}{:c}C - {}"     .format(day[0], from_to, 0x00b0, day[3])
```

See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Thnx for your reply. I was getting UnicodeEncodeError so I had to modify your code a bit: print "  {} {:>5}{}C - {}".format(day[0], from_to, u'\u00b0'.encode('UTF-8'), day[3])

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience - I added a more nice approach to the end of my answer.

Comment: To display 0x00b0 in Linux terminal would require some additional changes in environment variables and I would rather avoid that. u'\u00b0'.encode('UTF-8') avoids it.

Answer (score 2):

Another tip: Your *"2-lines returns"*, e. g.

```
    results = self._call(url)
    return results
```

have no advantage over the 1-line ones:

```
    return self._call(url)
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted this one from ancestor class and modified it to return temperatures in Celsius, but did no refactoring at all. Still a valid point. On the same note, I also stored reference to WeatherReport(args.location) in the report variable in the last line instead of just calling it with WeatherReport(parser.parse_args().location). Thnx again.

Answer (score 2):

If you swap first 2 lines in your function definition and use longer `"---"` strings you will reach more impressing visual aspect.

Compare

```
def show_location(self, location):
    print "-" * 50
    feedback = "10-day forecast for " + location.capitalize()
    print feedback.center(50)
    print "-" * 50
```

with

```
def show_location(self, location):
    feedback = "10-day forecast for " + location.capitalize()
    print "-------------------------" * 2
    print feedback.center(50)
    print "-------------------------" * 2
```

Comment: I think this one is a matter of personal preference. But, you gave me an idea: print "-"*50 + "\n", feedback.center(50) + "\n", "-"*50. Is there a way to get this using format()? I am not sure how to repeat string with it.

Comment: Good question - I posted it as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

The printing part of

```
def show_location(self, location):
    print "-" * 50
    feedback = "10-day forecast for " + location.capitalize()
    print feedback.center(50)
    print "-" * 50
```

may be one line

```
    print "{0}\n{1:^50}\n{0}".format("-"*50, feedback)
```

or

```
    print "{line}\n{fb:^50}\n{line}".format(line="-"*50, fb=feedback)
```

(It would be a little nicer if you first assign `"-"*50` to a variable, say `line`, and then use it.)

---

In both cases I used identifications of a placeholder (*numbers* in the 1<sup>st</sup> case, *names* in the 2<sup>nd</sup> one) to avoid the repetition of `"-"*50` - the *DRY* principle *(Don't Repeat Yourself)*.

Comment: Please keep your response together in one answer by editing :)